# How to use script variables in a plpgsql do block or function in a "right scope"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How do I use local script variables in a postgresql (version 9.4) script right, using the `plpgsql` language dialect? I try to get results of a status messages from the script, but get problems with the variables scope.

Here some example code:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Local variables conming  in 3 incarnations
-- ident, variable (single quotes, prefix VAR), 
-- quoted variable (quoted quotes, prefix QTL)
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Work schema 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
\set DB_SCHEMA           GT1
\set DB_VAR_SCHEMA       'GT1'
\set DB_QTL_SCHEMA       '\'':DB_VAR_SCHEMA'\''

-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Selector for the choosen raster 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
\set RS_VAR_PROJECT      'GT1'
\set RS_QTL_PROJECT       '\'':RS_VAR_PROJECT'\''
\set RS_VAR_VERSION      '2016-2.0KM-V1.0'
\set RS_QTL_VERSION      '\'':RS_VAR_VERSION'\''
...    

-- =================================================================
-- Information about Settings
-- =================================================================
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $INFO$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS IMPORT SCHEMA:   %', :DB_QTL_SCHEMA;
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS RASTER PROJECT:  %', :RST_QTL_PROJECT;
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS RASTER VERSION:  %', :RST_QTL_VERSION;
END $INFO$;

-- =================================================================
-- Clean up the temporary database schema
-- =================================================================
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS :DB_SCHEMA CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA :DB_SCHEMA;
....
```

It seems that variable is'nt visible in the psql language scope `DO $$... END $$`. So I get an error:

```
$ psql daisi_2017_06_06 < create-stats-schema.sql 
ERROR:  Syntax error at »:«
LINE 3: RAISE NOTICE 'DAISI STATISTIC IMPORT SCHEMA: %', :DB_QTL_SCH...
                                                         ^
```

OS: Linux DEBIAN 8; Postgresql 9.4

@Anuraag Veerapaneni: Providing the code block and error without the colon

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $INFO$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS IMPORT SCHEMA:   %', DB_QTL_SCHEMA;
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS RASTER PROJECT:  %', RST_QTL_PROJECT;
  RAISE NOTICE 'STATISTICS RASTER VERSION:  %', RST_QTL_VERSION;
END $INFO$;
```

Error original in german language:

```
$psql daisi_2017_06_06 < create-stats-schema.sql 
FEHLER:  Spalte »db_qtl_schema« existiert nicht
ZEILE 1: SELECT DB_QTL_SCHEMA
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The direct way doesn't work. There is a workaround based on GUC - global user configurations.

```
ides_jmmaj=# \set xxx 'Hello'
ides_jmmaj=# set custom.xxx to :'xxx';
SET

ides_jmmaj=# do $$
ides_jmmaj$# begin
ides_jmmaj$#   raise notice '%', current_setting('custom.xxx');
ides_jmmaj$# end;
ides_jmmaj$# $$;
NOTICE:  Hello
DO
```

The variable prefix like "custom." is mandatory - but there can be any text.

Comment: If I use this technique, do I have to care about the the peristence of these variables? The variables will remain in the database after closing the connection?

Comment: these variables are session only.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are referenced using % as shown below. Could you please remove ":" and check

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', variable_name;
```

Comment: There is also an error without the colon: QUERY:  SELECT DB_QTL_SCHEMA; CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL-Funktion inline_code_block line 3 at RAISE

Comment: Could you provide the code block where it is showing erroe